# How to automatically custom sort a Google Sheet by status

Tags: google-sheets, sorting

I have to sort a sheet of data based on changeable values of dropdowns for each row.

For example, I want all the waiters that are on-shift to have a **"Ready"** status from the dropdown. Those off-shift to have **"Off-shift"** status etc. Status is changed manually from the dropdown for each person, however, I need all the "Ready" waiters to appear on top, then all the "Off-shift" ones, then "On-vacation" ones etc. Each time a status from the dropdown is changed, the list should be re-sorted automatically.

As a novice I feel quite clueless on how to achieve this.. I tried to write a script based on similar cases I saw but it isn't working at all. Any clue on why and how it could work?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). See [Sort rows from highest to lower value problem](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/154004/269219).

Comment: This looks to be something that could be done by using the built-in filter and filter view features. Please start by reading [Sort & filter your data](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681?hl=en). If after doing that you still need help, please edit the question to show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].